# css not working locally after deploying the react app on github pages

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, github, github-pages

I reacently deployed a react application on **github pages** and it is **working fine** there(**GitHub-pages**) but afterwards when i am running my local code, the css is not working at all.

Comment: Your code works on server but not on local? You deserve a medal.

Comment: are you saying that BEFORE you deployed, it worked on localhost (that's what I've inferred from your question, perhaps wrongly)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Before the deployment of the code on github pages, css of my application was working perfectly fine but after the deployment the css file is not working at all, when i run it locally. However, on the server the css is working fine.